# Ajax request / unable to empty the global variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am very new to Javascript/jquery and async. I read a lot in this forum.
But i did not find a solution for my problem.

i get a JS File (logger.js) from a data logger like:

```
ab[cd++]="data1"
ab[cd++]="data2"
ab[cd++]="data3"
...
```

i try to load this file in a mobile App.

```
var ab = [];
var cd = 0;

with an ajax call:
    $.get("logger.js", function() {
        alert(ab.length); //3  works fine for the first request 
    });
....
ab.length = 0; //doesnt work.
```

on the second request `ab.length` is 6,
on the third  request `ab.length` is 9   and so on.

Where is the place to empty ab?

Comment: you need to ask a better question. I dont understand what you are asking.

Comment: ok sorry for that. my problem is, that i have to empty the array "ab" before the next Ajay Call is done. i tried it with ab=[] at the end of the callback function, but that did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You should redefine `ab` as an empty array:

```
ab = [];
```

Be aware that you are performing an ASYNC call, so make sure that you redefine your `ab` variable inside the callback function (my guess, i dont know where you are using it):

```
$.get("logger.js", function() {
    //do something with ab here and then redefine it.
    ab = [];
});
```

Comment: the problem was: i had to reset "cd" too, in the callback function. THX taxicala